# Retrieve data from mysql DB doesn't work /PHP

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch

I hvae the following PHP source:

```
$type_ID =$_GET["typeID"];
try{                               
$article_ID =$_GET["articleID"];
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE articleID=$article_ID && typeID=$type_ID");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE typeID=$type_ID");
                                   }
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query); 
echo '<h1>'.$row['articleTitle'].'</h1>';
echo  $row['articleContent'];
```

I know that this code is no safe, and yo can easlily do sql injection.

There problem here is that it's didn't go into the `catch` part (after the `try`)even when it should.
The solution may be easy but I can't solve it.

Why it's didn't go into the `catch` section?

Comment: Because you don't have any exception in the `try` part therefore it is not coming in catch block

Comment: There is no `throw new Exception`.

Comment: mysql_query will return false if it doesn't work, it won't throw an exception.

Comment: Okay, so how can I fix it? I'm pretty new in programming in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to change your queries to use the or to catch the fail in this case something like this may work though I'm not 100% (can anyone correct me?)  You'd be far better off moving away from mysql_ functions though and moving to mysqli or pdo in an OO style then you can better trap and handle the errors.

```
$type_ID =$_GET["typeID"];
try{                               
$article_ID =$_GET["articleID"];
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE articleID=$article_ID && typeID=$type_ID") or throw new Exception("ERROR HERE");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
 $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE typeID=$type_ID"); // note we can't throw exception here because its already in the try catch. perhaps we should look at something like the finally statement.
//echo $e->getMessage(); //uncomment this line if you want to output the exception error text set above
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_query); 
echo '<h1>'.$row['articleTitle'].'</h1>';
echo  $row['articleContent'];
```

Actually just had a thought you'd be much better doing something like this and validating your inputs before hand.  (note i'm doing no string escaping here don't forget to do it)

```
$type_ID =$_GET["typeID"];
$article_ID =$_GET["articleID"];

if (strlen($type_ID)>0 && strlen($article_ID)>0 && is_numeric($type_ID) && is_numeric($article_ID)) { 
$sqlquery = "SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE articleID=$article_ID && typeID=$type_ID";
} else {
$sqlquery = "SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE typeID=$type_ID";
}

try {
    $queryresult = mysql_query($sqlquery) or throw new Exception("Query Failed");
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

So basically you're validating and checking your inputs and switching your sql statements before then your try catch logic is purely for did the query succeed or fail which is far more sensible than what you were attempting.

Comment: Hi, thanks but now after copy that code the page doesn't load at all I get broser error :  HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): The system encountered an unexpected condition while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: I didn't test it so you'll have to kinda debug it yourself its more of a guideline.  it could be that the old mysql_ functions don't support "or throw new exception" in which case you're going to have to swap to mysqli or pdo as the try catch style of doing things is moer OO but the mysql_ functions are more functional

Comment: Also check your server error logs see what the error is it throws (or configure php to output the error to screen either works)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql query will return FALSE on error
So you can throw an exception for that
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT articleContent, articleTitle From articles WHERE articleID=$article_ID && typeID=$type_ID");`

`if(!$result) throw new Exception("Invalid query: ". mysql_error());`

And catch them in your catch block
`catch(Exception $e)
{ echo $e->getMessage()}`

Its up to you what you will do with it echo or log.